# ADN8810 control frequency from Arduino Due

Tags: arduino, spi, dac

Resurrecting a [3 year old project](https://github.com/aleksas/interferometer/tree/master/pcb). I'm skilled software engineer but new to electronics so it's a bit of a walk in the wood at night without a flashlight. The pcb has a [ADN8810 - 12-bit current source with an adjustable fullscale output current of up to 300 mA](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADN8810.pdf). My understanding is that the output current is controlled by [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface).

So the question is: **what is the maximum frequency I can change the current if ADN8810 is controlled by [Arduino Due](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-due) via SPI protocol?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum SCLK frequency, according to the datasheet, is 12.5 MHz, and a transfer takes 16 bits, so that limits your update rate to (12.5 / 16) MHz = 100 MHz / 128 = 781 kHz to begin with.

You have a settling time of the output of 3 µs, so, if you need accurate output after every time you write, that's take 16 / 12.5 µs + 3µs, but that's just latency; your effective possible rate of accurate change is 1/(3µs) = 333.33 kHz.

When you look at fig. 13, you'll find that the output impedance, however, starts drastically changing after ca. 1 kHz, so whether or not that works for you: depends on what you attach to it.

Regarding the Arduino Due: I'm not an Arduino expert, but an 84 MHz ARM Cortex-M3 like used on that board should do a couple MHz of SPI rate, easily. I don't know efficient the Arduino SPI library is – it might or might not be simple and close to the metal – but software is easy to replace; FreeRTOS runs on the Arduino Due, so you won't be maneuvering yourself into a development dead-end if the Arduino software platform doesn't work.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that current precision of current setting is ~0.07mA ( 300mA/2^12 ) ?

Comment: @alex can't answer that, don't know your schematic. Depends on how you set the current – and, DAC resolution isn't inherently the effective numbers of bits you get; a detailed analysis of this would leave the scope of this question and you should ask a new question including your schematic!